# Magento 2: Command to Clear view_preprocessed

Tags: magento2, frontend, bin-magento

Is there a Magento 2 `bin/magento` command to clear the `var/view_preprocessed` cache/pre-process folder without doing a full static asset refresh?  The `cache:clean` command doesn't clear this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any references that would exclusively clear

```
Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
const TMP_MATERIALIZATION_DIR = 'view_processed';
```

All methods that I did come across also included at least removing `DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW`

Combining something like the below with your excellent [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager)

```
\Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem::cleanupFilesystem([DirectoryList::TMP_MATERIALIZATION_DIR])
```

should get you close.